# Get current logged-in user from SharePoint in Bot Framework c#

Tags: azure, botframework, sharepoint-online, spfx

We are creating a chat bot using Azure in SharePoint and using it as iframe in spfx. We need to get the SharePoint current logged in user in azure.
Steps followed to create the chat bot:

- Created chatbot using azure bot framework.
- Called rest api to interact with SharePoint.
- Using Iframe in SharePoint SPFx extension to showcase the chatbot on site.

How to get the SharePoint current Logged-in user in bot framework?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts) and [repo](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-bot-framework-sso)  that can help you for share point SSO. OAuth services to support user sign-in and SSO. Below is the sample for S2S and user auth. Check out the whole list https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples.

[Bot-authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) demonstrates how to integrate OAuth providers for user authenticated flows.

Answer (score 0):

As the bot runs in the SPFx environment, you can get the current user info as below sample:

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-bot-framework-sso/webpart/src/webparts/botFrameworkChatSSO/components/BotFrameworkChatSSO.tsx

`const userId = props.context.pageContext.user.loginName;`

Or you can call the Rest API or Graph API to get the current user in SPFX.

- [Connect to SharePoint APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/connect-to-sharepoint)
- [Pnp Get Current user](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/site-users/#get-current-user)

BR